# (*mtx).lock(); causing Guru Meditation Error: Core 0 panic'ed as a result of too large of a string on an ESP32

Tags: string, base64, byte, buffer, esp32

I am experimenting with adding a Minecraft server favicon using the code from [this](https://github.com/nikisalli/esp32-minecraft-server) Github project designed for an ESP32.

My modified code is as follows:

```
#include "minecraft.h"
#include <chunk.h>

// PACKET
void packet::write(uint8_t val){
    buffer[index] = val;
    index ++;
}

void packet::write(uint8_t * buf, size_t size){
    memcpy(buffer + index, std::move(buf), size);
    index += size;
}

void packet::serverWriteVarInt(int32_t value){
    do {
        uint8_t temp = (uint8_t)(value & 0b01111111);
        value = lsr(value,7);
        if (value != 0) {
            temp |= 0b10000000;
        }
        S->write(temp);
    } while (value != 0);
}

void packet::writePacket(){
    Serial.println("INSIDE0");
    (*mtx).lock();
    Serial.println("INSIDE1");
    serverWriteVarInt(index);
    Serial.println("INSIDE2");
    S->write(buffer, index);
    Serial.println("INSIDE3");
    (*mtx).unlock();
}

// SERVERBOUND LOGIN
uint8_t minecraft::player::readHandShake(){
    readVarInt(); // length
    int id = readVarInt(); // packet id
    int protocol_version = readVarInt();
    readString(); // we don't need our name
    readUnsignedShort();
    int state = readVarInt();
    if(id != 0){
        return false;
    } else if(protocol_version != 754){
        logerr("wrong protocol version, log in with 1.16.5");
        return false;
    }

    if(state != 1 && state != 2) {
        logerr("wrong state");
        return 0;
    } else {
        return state;
    }
}

bool minecraft::player::readLoginStart(){
    readVarInt(); // length
    int id = readVarInt();
    if(id != 0){
        return false;
    }
    username = readString();
    loginfo("player logging in as " + username);
    return true;
}

uint64_t minecraft::player::readPing(){
    while(S->available() < 10);
    readVarInt(); // length
    readVarInt(); // packet id
    uint64_t payload = readLong(); // payload
    login("ping " + String((uint32_t)payload));
    return payload;
}

void minecraft::player::readRequest(){
    while(S->available() < 2);
    readVarInt();
    readVarInt();
    login("request packet received");
}

// SERVERBOUND PLAY PACKETS
void minecraft::player::readChat(){
    String m = readString();
    login("<" + username + "> " + m);
    if(m == "/stats"){
        writeChat("freeheap: " + String(esp_get_free_heap_size() / 1000) + "kB", "server");
    } else {
        mc->broadcastChatMessage(m, username);
    }
}

void minecraft::player::readPosition(){
    x = readDouble();
    y = readDouble();
    z = readDouble();
    on_ground = readBool();
    mc->broadcastPlayerPosAndLook(x, y, z, yaw_i, pitch_i, on_ground, id);
    // login("player pos " + String(x) + " " + String(y) + " " + String(z));
}

void minecraft::player::readRotation(){
    yaw = readFloat();
    pitch = readFloat();
    yaw_i = floor(fmap(yaw, 0, 360, 0, 256));
    pitch_i = floor(fmap(pitch, 0, 360, 0, 256));
    on_ground = readBool();
    mc->broadcastPlayerRotation(yaw_i, pitch_i, on_ground, id);
    // login("player rotation " + String(yaw) + " " + String(pitch));
}

void minecraft::player::readKeepAlive(){
    login("keepalive received: " + String((long)readLong()));
}

void minecraft::player::readPositionAndLook(){
    x = readDouble();
    y = readDouble();
    z = readDouble();
    yaw = readFloat();
    pitch = readFloat();
    yaw_i = floor(fmap(yaw, 0, 360, 0, 256));
    pitch_i = floor(fmap(pitch, 0, 360, 0, 256));
    on_ground = readBool();
    mc->broadcastPlayerPosAndLook(x, y, z, yaw_i, pitch_i, on_ground, id);
    // login("player rotation " + String(yaw) + " " + String(pitch));
}

void minecraft::player::readTeleportConfirm(){
    readVarInt();
    login("teleport confirm");
}

void minecraft::player::readAnimation(){
    mc->broadcastEntityAnimation(readVarInt(), id);  
}

void minecraft::player::readEntityAction(){
    readVarInt(); // we don't need our own id lmao
    mc->broadcastEntityAction(readVarInt(), id);
    readVarInt(); // we don't need horse jump boost
}

// CLIENTBOUND BROADCAST
void minecraft::broadcastChatMessage(String msg, String username){
    for(auto player : players){
        if(player.connected){
            player.writeChat(msg, username);
        }
    }
}

void minecraft::broadcastSpawnPlayer(){
    for(auto player : players){
        if(player.connected){
            for(auto p : players){
                if(p.id != player.id && p.connected){
                    player.writeSpawnPlayer(p.x, p.y, p.z, p.yaw_i, p.pitch_i, p.id);
                    player.writeEntityLook(p.yaw_i, p.id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void minecraft::broadcastPlayerPosAndLook(double x, double y, double z, int _yaw_i, int _pitch_i, bool on_ground, uint8_t id){
    for(auto player : players){
        if(player.connected && player.id != id){
            player.writeEntityTeleport(x, y, z, _yaw_i, _pitch_i, on_ground, id);
            player.writeEntityLook(_yaw_i, id);
        }
    }
}

void minecraft::broadcastPlayerRotation(int _yaw_i, int _pitch_i, bool on_ground, uint8_t id){
    for(auto player : players){
        if(player.connected && player.id != id){
            player.writeEntityRotation(_yaw_i, _pitch_i, on_ground, id);
            player.writeEntityLook(_yaw_i, id);
        }
    }
}

void minecraft::broadcastEntityAnimation(uint8_t anim, uint8_t id){
    for(auto player : players){
        if(player.connected && player.id != id){
            player.writeEntityAnimation(anim, id);
        }
    }
}

void minecraft::broadcastEntityAction(uint8_t action, uint8_t id){
    for(auto player : players){
        if(player.connected && player.id != id){
            player.writeEntityAction(action, id);
        }
    }
}

void minecraft::broadcastEntityDestroy(uint8_t id){
    for(auto player : players){
        if(player.connected && player.id != id){
            player.writeEntityDestroy(id);
        }
    }
}

void minecraft::broadcastPlayerInfo(){
    // calculate data length in a horrible non-automated way for now TODO
    uint32_t num = getPlayerNum();
    uint32_t len = 3 + (21 * num);
    for(auto player : players){
        if(player.connected){
            len += player.username.length();
        }
    }
    // broadcast playerinfo
    for(auto player : players){
        if(player.connected){
            packet pac(player.S, player.mtx);
            pac.writeVarInt(0x32);
            pac.writeVarInt(0); // action add player
            pac.writeVarInt(num); // number of players
            for(auto p : players){
                if(p.connected){
                    pac.writeUUID(p.id); // first player's uuid
                    pac.writeString(p.username);
                    pac.writeVarInt(0); // no properties given
                    pac.writeVarInt(1); // gamemode
                    pac.writeVarInt(100); // hardcoded ping TODO
                    pac.writeBoolean(0); // has display name
                }
            }
            pac.writePacket();
            player.login("player info sent");
        }
    }
}

uint8_t minecraft::getPlayerNum(){
    uint8_t i = 0;
    for(auto player : players){
        if(player.connected) i++;
    }
    return i;
}

// CLIENTBOUND PLAYER
void minecraft::player::writeChat(String msg, String username){
    packet p(S, mtx);
    String s = "{\"text\": \"<" + username + "> " + msg + "\",\"bold\": \"false\"}";
    p.writeVarInt(0x0E);
    p.writeString(s);
    p.writeByte(0);
    p.writeUUID(id);
    p.writePacket();
}

void minecraft::player::writeLoginSuccess(){
    packet p(S, mtx);
    p.writeVarInt(0x02);
    p.writeUUID(id);
    p.writeString(username);
    p.writePacket();
    logout("login success sent");
}

void minecraft::player::writeChunk(uint8_t x, uint8_t y){
    packet p(S, mtx);
    p.writeVarInt(0x20); 
    p.writeInt(x); // X
    p.writeInt(y); // Z
    p.writeBoolean(1); // full chunk yes
    p.writeVarInt(0x01); //bitmask set to 0xFF because we're sending the whole chunk

    p.write(height_map_NBT, sizeof(height_map_NBT) / sizeof(height_map_NBT[0]));

    uint8_t b[1024];
    memset(b, 127, 1024);
    p.writeVarInt(1024); // array length 2 bytes as varint
    p.write(b, 1024); // 127 = void biome
    
    p.writeVarInt(4487); // magic 

    p.writeShort(1); // non-air blocks (can't be bothered calculating it and the client doesn't need it)
    p.writeUnsignedByte(8); // bits per block
    p.writeVarInt(256); // palette length 8 bits per block
    p.write(palette, 384); // write palette
    p.writeVarInt(512); // we're sending 512 longs or 4096 bytes
    uint8_t * buf = (uint8_t*)chunk[x][y];
    p.write(buf, 4096);

    p.writeVarInt(0); // no block entities
    p.writePacket();
    logout("chunk sent");
}

void minecraft::player::writePlayerPositionAndLook(double x, double y, double z, float _yaw, float _pitch, uint8_t flags){
    packet p(S, mtx);
    p.writeVarInt(0x34);
    p.writeDouble(x);
    p.writeDouble(y);
    p.writeDouble(z);
    p.writeFloat(_yaw);
    p.writeFloat(_pitch);
    p.writeUnsignedByte(flags);
    p.writeVarInt(0x55);
    p.writePacket();
    logout("player position and look sent");
}

void minecraft::player::writeKeepAlive(){
    packet p(S, mtx);
    p.writeVarInt(0x1F);
    uint32_t num = millis()/1000;
    p.writeLong(num);
    logout("keepalive sent: " + String(num));
    p.writePacket();
}

void minecraft::player::writeServerDifficulty(){
    packet p(S, mtx);
    p.writeVarInt(0x0D);
    p.writeUnsignedByte(0);
    p.writeBoolean(1);
    logout("server difficulty packet sent");
    p.writePacket();
}

void minecraft::player::writeSpawnPlayer(double x, double y, double z, int _yaw_i, int _pitch_i, uint8_t id){
    packet p(S, mtx);
    p.writeVarInt(0x04);
    p.writeVarInt(id); // player id
    p.writeUUID(id); // player uuid
    p.writeDouble(x); // player x
    p.writeDouble(y); // player y
    p.writeDouble(z); // player z
    p.writeUnsignedByte(_yaw_i); // player yaw
    p.writeUnsignedByte(_pitch_i); // player pitch
    p.writePacket();
    logout("spawn player sent id:" + String(id));
}

void minecraft::player::writeJoinGame(){
    packet p(S, mtx);
    p.writeVarInt(0x24);
    p.writeInt(id); // entity id
    p.writeBoolean(0); // is hardcore
    p.writeUnsignedByte(1); // gamemode
    p.writeByte(-1); // previous gamemode
    p.writeVarInt(1); // only one world
    p.writeString("minecraft:overworld"); // only one world
    p.write(dimension_codec_NBT, sizeof(dimension_codec_NBT) / sizeof(dimension_codec_NBT[0])); // NBT with world settings
    p.write(dimension_NBT, sizeof(dimension_NBT) / sizeof(dimension_NBT[0])); // NBT with world settings
    p.writeString("minecraft:overworld"); // spawn world
    p.writeLong(0); // hashed seed
    p.writeVarInt(10); // max players
    p.writeVarInt(12); // view distance
    p.writeBoolean(0); // reduced debug info
    p.writeBoolean(0); // enable respawn screen
    p.writeBoolean(0); // is debug world
    p.writeBoolean(1); // is flat
    logout("join game packet sent");
    p.writePacket();
}

void minecraft::player::writeResponse(){
    packet p(S, mtx);
    p.writeVarInt(0);
    // testing below
    p.writeString("{\"version\":{\"name\":\"1.16.5\",\"protocol\":754},\"players\":{\"max\":5,\"online\":5,\"sample\":[{\"name\":\"L_S___S_S_S__S_L\",\"id\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\"},{\"name\":\"L_SS__S_S_S_S__L\",\"id\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001\"},{\"name\":\"L_S_S_S_S_SS___L\",\"id\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002\"},{\"name\":\"L_S__SS_S_S_S__L\",\"id\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003\"},{\"name\":\"L_S___S_S_S__S_L\",\"id\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000004\"}]},\"description\":{\"text\":\"esp32 server\"},\"favicon\":\"<5527 characters in here>\"}");
    logout("response packet sent");
    Serial.println("WORKED2");
    p.writePacket();
    Serial.println("WORKED3");
}

void minecraft::player::writePong(uint64_t payload){
    packet p(S, mtx);
    p.writeVarInt(0x01); // packet id
    p.writeLong(payload); // payload
    logout("pong");
    p.writePacket();
}

void minecraft::player::writeEntityTeleport(double x, double y, double z, int _yaw_i, int _pitch_i, bool on_ground, uint8_t id){
    packet p(S, mtx);
    p.writeVarInt(0x56); // packet id
    p.writeVarInt(id);
    p.writeDouble(x);
    p.writeDouble(y);
    p.writeDouble(z);
    p.writeByte(_yaw_i);
    p.writeByte(_pitch_i);
    p.writeBoolean(on_ground);
    p.writePacket();
}

void minecraft::player::writeEntityRotation(int _yaw_i, int _pitch_i, bool on_ground, uint8_t id){
    packet p(S, mtx);
    p.writeVarInt(0x29); // packet id
    p.writeVarInt(id);
    p.writeByte(_yaw_i);
    p.writeByte(_pitch_i);
    p.writeBoolean(on_ground);
    p.writePacket();
}

void minecraft::player::writeEntityLook(int _yaw_i, uint8_t id){
    packet p(S, mtx);
    p.writeVarInt(0x3A); // packet id
    p.writeVarInt(id);
    p.writeByte(_yaw_i);
    p.writePacket();
}

void minecraft::player::writeEntityAnimation(uint8_t anim, uint8_t id){
    packet p(S, mtx);
    p.writeVarInt(0x05); // packet id
    p.writeVarInt(id);
    switch(anim){
        case 0:
            p.writeByte(0);
            break;
        case 1:
            p.writeByte(3);
            break;
    }
    p.writePacket();
}

void minecraft::player::writeEntityAction(uint8_t action, uint8_t id){
    packet p(S, mtx);
    p.writeVarInt(0x44); // packet id
    p.writeVarInt(id);
    switch(action){
        case 0:
            p.writeUnsignedByte(6); // field unique id
            p.writeVarInt(18); // we need only poses since swimming etc. isn't supported
            p.writeVarInt(5); // sneak
            break;
        case 1:
            p.writeUnsignedByte(6); // field unique id
            p.writeVarInt(18); // we need only poses since swimming etc. isn't supported
            p.writeVarInt(0); // stand
            break;
    }
    p.writeUnsignedByte(0xFF); // terminate entity metadata array
    p.writePacket();
}

void minecraft::player::writeEntityDestroy(uint8_t id){
    packet p(S, mtx);
    p.writeVarInt(0x36); // packet id
    p.writeVarInt(1); // entity count
    p.writeVarInt(id);
    p.writePacket();
}

// READ TYPES
uint16_t minecraft::player::readUnsignedShort(){
    while(S->available() < 2);
    int ret = S->read();
    return (ret << 8) | S->read();
}

float minecraft::player::readFloat(){
    char b[4] = {};
    while(S->available() < 4);
    for(int i=3; i>=0; i--){
        b[i] = S->read();
    }
    float f = 0;
    memcpy(&f, b, sizeof(float));
    return f;
}

double minecraft::player::readDouble(){
    char b[8] = {};
    while(S->available() < 8);
    for(int i=7; i>=0; i--){
        b[i] = S->read();
    }
    double d = 0;
    memcpy(&d, b, sizeof(double));
    return d;
}

int64_t minecraft::player::readLong(){
    char b[8] = {};
    while(S->available() < 8);
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
        b[i] = S->read();
    }
    uint64_t l = ((uint64_t) b[0] << 56)
       | ((uint64_t) b[1] & 0xff) << 48
       | ((uint64_t) b[2] & 0xff) << 40
       | ((uint64_t) b[3] & 0xff) << 32
       | ((uint64_t) b[4] & 0xff) << 24
       | ((uint64_t) b[5] & 0xff) << 16
       | ((uint64_t) b[6] & 0xff) << 8
       | ((uint64_t) b[7] & 0xff);
    return l;
}

String minecraft::player::readString(){
    int length = readVarInt();
    String result;
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        while (S->available() < 1);
        result.concat((char)S->read());
    }
    return result;
}

int32_t minecraft::player::readVarInt() {
    int numRead = 0;
    int result = 0;
    byte read;
    do {
        while (S->available() < 1);
        read = S->read();
        int value = (read & 0b01111111);
        result |= (value << (7 * numRead));
        numRead++;
        if (numRead > 5) {
            logerr("VarInt too big");
        }
    } while ((read & 0b10000000) != 0);
    return result;
}

uint8_t minecraft::player::readByte(){
    return S->read();
}

bool minecraft::player::readBool(){
    return S->read();
}

// WRITE TYPES
void packet::writeDouble(double value){
    unsigned char * p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&value);
    for(int i=7; i>=0; i--){
        write(p[i]);
    }
}

void packet::writeFloat(float value) {
    unsigned char * p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&value);
    for(int i=3; i>=0; i--){
        write(p[i]);
    }
}

void packet::writeVarInt(int32_t value) {
    do {
        uint8_t temp = (uint8_t)(value & 0b01111111);
        value = lsr(value,7);
        if (value != 0) {
            temp |= 0b10000000;
        }
        write(temp);
    } while (value != 0);
}

void packet::writeVarLong(int64_t value) {
    do {
        byte temp = (byte)(value & 0b01111111);
        value = lsr(value,7);
        if (value != 0) {
            temp |= 0b10000000;
        }
        write(temp);
    } while (value != 0);
}

void packet::writeString(String str){
    int length = str.length();
    byte *buf = new byte[length + 1]; // Dynamically allocate memory for buf
    str.getBytes(buf, length + 1);
    writeVarInt(length);
    Serial.print("Buffer size: ");
    Serial.println(length + 1); // Print size of the buffer
    Serial.print("String size: ");
    Serial.println(str.length());
    write(buf, length);
    Serial.println("WORKED");
    delete[] buf; // Free the allocated memory
}

void packet::writeLong(int64_t num){
    for(int i=7; i>=0; i--){
        write((uint8_t)((num >> (i*8)) & 0xff));
    }
}

void packet::writeUnsignedLong(uint64_t num){
    for(int i=7; i>=0; i--){
        write((uint8_t)((num >> (i*8)) & 0xff));
    }
}

void packet::writeUnsignedShort(uint16_t num){
    write((byte)((num >> 8) & 0xff));
    write((byte)(num & 0xff));
}

void packet::writeUnsignedByte(uint8_t num){
    write(num);
}

void packet::writeInt(int32_t num){
    write((byte)((num >> 24) & 0xff));
    write((byte)((num >> 16) & 0xff));
    write((byte)((num >> 8) & 0xff));
    write((byte)(num & 0xff));
}

void packet::writeShort(int16_t num){
    write((byte)((num >> 8) & 0xff));
    write((byte)(num & 0xff));
}

void packet::writeByte(int8_t num){
    write(num);
}

void packet::writeBoolean(uint8_t val){
    write(val);
}

void packet::writeUUID(int user_id){
    uint8_t b[15] = {0};
    write(b, 15);
    write(user_id);
}

void minecraft::player::writeLength(uint32_t length){
    do {
        uint8_t temp = (uint8_t)(length & 0b01111111);
        length = lsr(length,7);
        if (length != 0) {
            temp |= 0b10000000;
        }
        S->write(temp);
    } while (length != 0);
}

// HANDLERS
bool minecraft::player::join(){
    uint8_t res = readHandShake();
    if(res == 1){
        readRequest();
        delay(1000);
        writeResponse();
        uint64_t payload = readPing();
        writePong(payload);
        return false;
    } else if(res == 2){
        if(!readLoginStart()) return false;
        writeLoginSuccess();
    }
    connected = true;
    writeJoinGame();
    writePlayerPositionAndLook(0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0x00);
    writeServerDifficulty();
    writeChunk(0, 0);
    writeChunk(0, 1);
    writeChunk(1, 0);
    writeChunk(1, 1);
    mc->broadcastPlayerInfo();
    mc->broadcastChatMessage(username + " joined the server", "Server");
    mc->broadcastSpawnPlayer();
    return true;
}

void minecraft::handle(){
    for(auto player : players){
        if(player.connected){
            player.writeKeepAlive();
        }
    }
}

void minecraft::player::handle(){
    if(S->available() > 2){
        uint32_t length = S->read();
        uint32_t packetid = S->read();
        switch (packetid){
        case 0x03:
            readChat();
            break;
        case 0x12:
            readPosition();
            break;
        case 0x14:
            readRotation();
            break;
        case 0x10:
            readKeepAlive();
            break;
        case 0x13:
            readPositionAndLook();
            break;
        case 0x00:
            readTeleportConfirm();
            break;
        case 0x2C:
            readAnimation();
            break;
        case 0x1C:
            readEntityAction();
            break;
        default:
            loginfo("id: 0x" + String(packetid, HEX) + " length: " + String(length));
            for(int i=0; i < length - VarIntLength(packetid); i++ ){
                while (S->available() < 1);
                // loginfo("packet id " + String(packetid));
                S->read();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

// UTILITIES
void minecraft::player::loginfo(String msg){
    Serial.println( "[INFO] p" + String(id) + " " + msg);
}

void minecraft::player::logerr(String msg){
    Serial.println( "[ERROR] p" + String(id) + " " + msg);
}

void minecraft::player::login(String msg){
    Serial.println( "[INFO] p" + String(id) + " <- " + msg);
}

void minecraft::player::logout(String msg){
    Serial.println( "[INFO] p" + String(id) + " -> " + msg);
}

int32_t lsr(int32_t x, uint32_t n){
  return (int32_t)((uint32_t)x >> n);
}

uint32_t minecraft::player::VarIntLength(int val) {
    if(val == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    return (int)floor(log(val) / log(128)) + 1;
}

float fmap(float x, float in_min, float in_max, float out_min, float out_max) {
  return (float)(x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (float)(in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```

I have found that if the string in `p.writeString("{\"version\"...` (line 376) is too long containing the favicon, I get an error which is related to the line `(*mtx).lock();` being     `Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.`.

The maximum buffer size (which is length) without error is 5998. Any higher and I start getting errors.

The serial output is as follows for the above code:

```
Connected to the WiFi network
172.20.10.5
[INFO] server started
[INFO] New client connected: 0
[INFO] p0 started task 0 pinned to core 0
[INFO] p0 <- request packet received
Buffer size: 6025
String size: 6024
WORKED
[INFO] p0 -> response packet sent
WORKED2
INSIDE0
Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core  0 register dump:
PC      : 0x400828ff  PS      : 0x00060730  A0      : 0x80082952  A1      : 0x3ffef080
A2      : 0x006458c0  A3      : 0xffffffff  A4      : 0x00000007  A5      : 0x0000ff00  
A6      : 0x00ff0000  A7      : 0xff000000  A8      : 0x00000016  A9      : 0x3ffef060
A10     : 0x00000002  A11     : 0x3f405da3  A12     : 0x00000007  A13     : 0x0000ff00  
A14     : 0x00ff0000  A15     : 0xff000000  SAR     : 0x0000001a  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c
EXCVADDR: 0x006458c4  LBEG    : 0x40089d91  LEND    : 0x40089da1  LCOUNT  : 0xffffffff  


Backtrace: 0x400828fc:0x3ffef080 0x4008294f:0x3ffef0a0 0x400d3088:0x3ffef0c0 0x400d5459:0x3ffef0e0 0x400d54d3:0x3fff0890 0x400d2a89:0x3fff0910

  #0  0x400828fc:0x3ffef080 in pthread_mutex_lock_internal at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/pthread/pthread.c:607
  #1  0x4008294f:0x3ffef0a0 in pthread_mutex_lock at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/pthread/pthread.c:650
  #2  0x400d3088:0x3ffef0c0 in packet::writePacket() at c:\users\elect\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa-esp32@8.4.0+2021r2-patch5\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\8.4.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\no-rtti\bits/gthr-default.h:761    
      (inlined by) std::mutex::lock() at c:\users\elect\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa-esp32@8.4.0+2021r2-patch5\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\8.4.0\bits/std_mutex.h:103
      (inlined by) packet::writePacket() at lib/minecraft/minecraft.cpp:28
  #3  0x400d5459:0x3ffef0e0 in minecraft::player::writeResponse() at lib/minecraft/minecraft.cpp:379 (discriminator 3)
  #4  0x400d54d3:0x3fff0890 in minecraft::player::join() at lib/minecraft/minecraft.cpp:677
  #5  0x400d2a89:0x3fff0910 in playerHandler(void*) at src/main.cpp:30 (discriminator 15)




ELF file SHA256: 3397051eb98a44ef

Rebooting...
```

The serial output when the buffer size (length) is 5999. Note the error is different:

```
Connecting to WiFi...
Connected to the WiFi network
172.20.10.5
[INFO] server started
[INFO] New client connected: 0
[INFO] p0 started task 0 pinned to core 0
[INFO] p0 <- request packet received
Buffer size: 5999
String size: 5998
WORKED
[INFO] p0 -> response packet sent
WORKED2
INSIDE0
INSIDE1
INSIDE2
INSIDE3
WORKED3
[INFO] New client connected: 0
[INFO] p0 started task 0 pinned to core 0
[ERROR] p0 wrong protocol version, log in with 1.16.5
[INFO] p0 <- ping 1124105216
[INFO] p0 -> pong
INSIDE0
INSIDE1
Buffer size: 20
String size: 19
WORKED
Buffer size: 20
String size: 19
WORKED
[INFO] p0 -> join game packet sent
INSIDE0
INSIDE2
[ 20555][E][WiFiClient.cpp:429] write(): fail on fd 50, errno: 104, "Connection reset by peer"
INSIDE3
INSIDE1
INSIDE2
INSIDE3
[INFO] p0 client 0 disconnected
```

I'm seeking answers to the following questions:

1. What is causing this issue?
2. What is the limit to the length of the string? I've found [here](https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=1542) and [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/issue-with-long-strings-and-preferences-library/1038837) mention of a limit of 4000 bytes, but this does not appear to align with my experience.
3. Is there something significant about the maximum length of 5998 or is this just an arbitrary length limit?
4. Is there a way of processing the favicon other than the current png -> 'base64 as a string' process I am using to allow for longer inputs?

Thanks in advance!